# How to configure Hibernate to make table/column name with uppercase AND lowercase letters

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have to use table and column names in my Postgres that **contain uppercase and lowercase letters**. For example `OrgInfo`

I would like to create such tables and columns using **Hibernate**. If I use standard approach:

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "OrgInfo")
```

then I receive the table with the name "org_info".

How I can configure Hibernate to create tables and columns with exact given names including uppercase and lowercase letters?

I have tried to use

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "\"OrgInfo\"")
```

with no effect.

Also I use Spring Boot and have tried to configure like this:

> spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy =
>   org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy OR
>   spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy =
>   org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

Comment: While you can probably convince your obfuscation layer to do so, I would **strongly** recommend against using `CamelCase`. The usual naming convention in Postgres is to use `snake_case` - you will save yourself a lot of trouble if you stick to that.

Comment: Isn't that specifically related to the DBMS itself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to configure Hibernate "physical-strategy" in your configuration file as follows:

> spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

Comment: @AlessandroC what is the new issue u r getting?

Comment: I tried that setting but nothing changed until I grew up the version of Spring Boot.

Answer (score 3):

The working solution is to use both parts:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"OrgInfo\"")
```

and

> spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Entity @Table(name = "\"OrgInfo\"")
```

Comment: Nope. It might need to configure Hibernate naming strategies somehow for such approach work.

Answer (score 0):

application.yml version of the answer by @Sachin:

```
hibernate:
        physical_naming_strategy: 'org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl'
```