# The name of database and for each table isn't uppercase in the first letter of the word when I using JPA Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, mariadb, uppercase

Hi everyone who read this post, I have a problem about when I tried to make Hibernate between Java code and MariaDB. When it's running, it created database and tables, but the problem is the name of database and all the tables in my database is not uppercase in the first letter of word. Guys, how can I resolve problem?
[Image Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRsG2.png)
My persistence.xml:
`

```
<persistence-unit name="qlch_nhom8">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>

        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/QLCHTT?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="123456789"/>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
        <property name="hibernate.physical_naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

`

I have tried only MariaDB also SQL Server is still appeared this happend. Although it's not problem about error running code but for me it's look not good eye.

Comment: https://mariadb.com/docs/skysql-dbaas/ref/mdb/system-variables/lower_case_table_names/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure Hibernate to make table/column name with uppercase AND lowercase letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46052297/how-to-configure-hibernate-to-make-table-column-name-with-uppercase-and-lowercas)

Comment: Please do not post images of text, but the text directly.